# Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was using the Material UI `Timepicker` but after updating to Material UI 5 it is not working anymore. I updated everything to `@next` and `@material-ui/core` (version 5.0.0-beta.5) and `@material-ui/lab` (version: 5.0.0-alpha.44).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you copy the `Timepicker` code from the MUI docs, you also need to install the lab package which contains the adapter code to integrate with `date-fns`. See the requirements [here](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#requirements). For reference, you can see the [package.json](https://codesandbox.io/s/ml33b?file=/package.json) file from the live demo.

```sh
npm i @mui/lab
```

Comment: @diabetico if you're updating to MUI v5, you should change the name from `@material-ui/core` to `@mui/material`. See the [installation](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#npm) guide.

Answer (score 5):

As of Oct 2022, to fix this issue, use

```
npm i @mui/x-date-pickers
```

[Read further more on dependencies requirement](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/x-date-pickers)
It supports 4 different date-libraries as of now. It is not mandatory to install all of them, choose as per project requirement

```
date-fns 
Day.js
Luxon
Moment.js
```

Elaborating on date-fns is like manipulating the results of MUI date-picker in required format

```
import { format, compareAsc } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(2014, 1, 11), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
//=> '02/11/2014'

const dates = [
  new Date(1995, 6, 2),
  new Date(1987, 1, 11),
  new Date(1989, 6, 10),
]
dates.sort(compareAsc)
//=> [
//   Wed Feb 11 1987 00:00:00,
//   Mon Jul 10 1989 00:00:00,
//   Sun Jul 02 1995 00:00:00
// ]
```

Answer (score 3):

sometimes it just needs this :

```
yarn add @mui/lab
```

Comment: In spite of it being so simple, this was the right answer for me :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What I did was installing date-fns as well

```
  npm i date-fns
```

I then stopped the localhost server and restart it again with npm start (I was using react)

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

install both
npm i @mui/lab and npm i @mui/material

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue use below commend. It's worked for me.

```
npm install @mui/x-date-pickers
```

Answer (score -1):

If after installing `@mui/lab` it doesn't work, You can add:

```
npm i @mui/material
```

Or

```
yarn add @mui/material
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).